# zsh: rename file if file in subfolder has same name

Tags: zsh

There is the following file structure:

```
charlie
├──this-file.foo.1
├──this-file.foo.2
└──this-file.foo.3
foxtrot
├──another-file.foo.1
├──another-file.foo.2
├──another-file.foo.3.bar
├──another-file.foo.4.baz
└──another-file.foo.5.qux
this-file.waldo
another-file.waldo
```

I would like to rename all files in the root folder, in this case `this-file.waldo` and `another-file.waldo`. If in any subfolder there exists a file with the same base name as a .waldo file, then I would like to rename the .waldo file using the name of the subfolder that contains the namesake like so:

```
charlie
├──this-file.foo.1
├──this-file.foo.2
└──this-file.foo.3
foxtrot
├──another-file.foo.1
├──another-file.foo.2
├──another-file.foo.3.bar
├──another-file.foo.4.baz
└──another-file.foo.5.qux
charlie.waldo
foxtrot.waldo
```

The file has to be renamed if and only if a subfolder has a file which shares the same base name, and it has to be renamed with the same name as the subfolder.

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

- There will always be a .waldo file present.
- If there is no file that shares the base name it should just ignore and go on to the next one until it finds a match.
- Filenames are normal OS filenames, so yes, there may be &()[]# etc. present.

Comment: Will there always be a `*.waldo` file? What do you want to do if there's no "file which shares the same base name"? Are all the filenames clean (no spaces, no funny characters)? Please [edit] your question to add this info, don't reply via comment. `man find` may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be something like:

```
for f (*.waldo(N)) (){ (($#)) && echo mv -- $f $1:h.waldo; } */$f:r.*(NY1)
```

(remove the `echo` (dry-run) if happy).

Some of the less usual zsh features found there:

- `for f (values) action`: short form of the for loop (similar to perl syntax)
- `() { body; } args`: anonymous function
- `$var:r`: `r`oot name (part without extension, like in csh/vim...)
- `$var:h`: `h`ead (dirname, like in csh/vim)
- `(N)`: `N`ullglob glob qualifier: so it doesn't report an error if there's no match:
- `(Y1)`: stop after the first match glob qualifier.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Walking through this with the for manpage really opens my eyes as to how for looping in zsh works. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you get a list of all files in the current directory

```bsh
files=(*(.DoN))
```

then, you do something to each of them:

```bsh
for file in $files; do
  # get the basename
  bname="${file%%.*}"
  # look for matches in subfolders
  typeset -a matches_in_subfolders
  matches_in_subfolders=*/${bname}*
  # Check whether list of matches is longer than 0
  if [ ${#matches_in_subfolders[@]} -gt 0 ] ; then
    # do your magic renaming here
  fi
done
```

Didn't do the renaming for you here, because I'm not sure how to deal with multiple findings, but

```
mv -- "${file}" "${matches_in_subfolders[0]}${file#*.}"
```

would rename `file` to the name of the first folder containing it, and the longest extension it had (if it's not `.waldo`, but `.foo.waldo`, I assume you want `charlie.foo.waldo`, not just `charlie.waldo`).

Comment: honestly, haven't tested this.

Comment: This gives me a `mv: rename *(.DoN) to DoN): No such file or directory` error. I will be retrying with a version `find "$PWD"/${dir}/*  -type f`

Comment: err, wait, forgot `()` around `*.(.DoN)`